# How to access a class object from an other class

Tags: php, class, oop

My question is if i can access a class object from another class without the second one being extending the first one:

```
<?php 
class MySQL {
    public function query($data){
        //do something
    }
?>
<?php 
class Users {
    public function getUser($id){
        MySQL::query($data); // or $MySQL->query();
        return $something;
    } 
?>
```

Is this possible? Or has the second class being extending the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access like this `MySQL::query`, then `query` method should be static.

Otherwise you need to instantiate a new object from MySQL class:

```
class Users {

    public function getUser($id) {
        //MySQL::query($data); //Static way
        $MySQL = new MySQL();
        $something = $MySQL->query($mydata);
        return $something;
    }
}
```

Comment: And can the $MySQL class be initiated from the begining of the Users class, so I can call it from every function that the Users class has?

Comment: Errr.. not as you think.  you can define a `private $MySQL;` variable in your class, at the variable declaration section. And when you in the `__construct();`, you can set `$this->MySQL = new MySQL();` so later inside your class, you can use everywhere the `$this->MySQL->query($data)` or any other non privet method of `MySQL` class. Read about the classes through examples.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of dependecy injection it woul look like this:

```
class MySQL {
    public function query($data){
        //do something
    }
}

class Users {
    private $mysql;

    public __construct($mysql){
        $this->mysql = $mysql
    }

    public function getUser($id){
        $this->mysql->query($data);
        return $something;
    } 
}

$mysql = new MySql();
$users = new Users($mysql);
```

Comment: I would do that a bit differently. Class users should not depend on class MySql and it should not be concerned what connection it will be using, agree? Today is MySql, but tomorrow it might be any other.
So, i would create an interface called DbConectionInterface, with public function query(); and then create a class MySql implements DbConnectionInterface and implement MySql query method. One of the rules of thumb for me is code to interface not to concrete class. Cheers

Comment: You're totally right of course... but when I read the question, I'm afraid that this might be a little overkill. ;)